# Doing a Union using linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to query two tables using linq in c#. The two tables are ManagerStrategy and Fund table. One Manager Strategy will have one or more funds. I basically need a result set that would return data in the following format. The Fund table has managerstrategy_id foreign key

For e.g

```
 ManagerStategyId, ManagerStrategyName
 ManagerStrategyId, FundName
 ManagerStrategyId, FundName
 ManagerStrategyId, FundName
 ManagerStategyId, ManagerStrategyName
 ManagerStrategyId, FundName
 ManagerStrategyId, FundName
```

I have tried the following query but not sure how to pull data according to the format above

```
  const int INVESTED = 1;
  const int REDEEMING = 4;
  const int ILIQUID = 134;
```

I have tried below but not sure if it is right and efficient way to using linq?

What I am trying to do is get a list of Strategies if Id and Name pair. Get a list of funds that match the strategies. Generate a list of that contains again Id and Name pair. The id here would be the foreign key in the funds table. The last step is doing a union of this list and the strategies list to get the above format.

Getting all the strategies based on filter condition

```
var strategies = GetService<MANAGERSTRATEGY>().Where(x => x.INVESTMENT_STATUS_ID == INVESTED || x.INVESTMENT_STATUS_ID == REDEEMING || x.INVESTMENT_STATUS_ID == ILIQUID).Select(x => new ListItemVM() {Id = x.ID, Name = x.NAME_TEXT}).ToList();
```

fetching all the funds

```
 var funds = GetService<FUND>().GetAll().Select(x => new ListItemVM() { Id = x.MANAGERSTRATEGY_ID.GetValueOrDefault(), Name = x.NAME_TEXT }).ToList();
```

Doing an inner join to fetch funds that have matching strategies

```
var strategyFunds = strategies.Join(funds, x => x.Id, y => y.Id,(x, y) => new ListItemVM() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).ToList();
```

Doing an Union to get Strategies and Funds in one list.

```
var managerStrategyFunds = strategies.Union(strategyFunds);

 var managerStrategyFundViewModel = new List<ManagerStrategyFundViewModel>();

                foreach (var item in managerStrategyFunds)
                {

                    var summary = new ManagerStrategyFundViewModel
                    {
                        ManagerStrategyId = item.Id,
                        ManagerStrategyName = item.Name
                    };

                    managerStrategyFundViewModel.Add(summary);
                }

                var viewModel = managerStrategyFundViewModel.OrderBy(x => x.ManagerStrategyName).ToList();

                return viewModel;
```

Comment: LINQ has a `UNION` method `Union` and a `UNION ALL` method `Concat`.

Comment: Can you show me how to use it ? consider there are two lists managerStrategies and managerFunds

Comment: Your question isn't very clear as written - try to clarify it?

Comment: @NetMage Wow.. I wish everyone gets the same chance and doesn't just get marked as too broad or negative down to infinity :)

Comment: Hi all , I have updated the post with comments on each line code to explain what I am doing. I am not sure its the best way that I am doing using linq and if it will work.

Comment: I have just seen the output and it is not desired output. What I am now getting is duplicated id and names in the list. What I was expecting to see the list of strategies followed by its funds in the same list

Comment: What are the types of `strategies` and `funds`? Is there some type of data layer involved? Can't you get the strategies and funds in one call?

Comment: Yes they can be got in one call. Thats what I am trying to achieve above. In my controller code , I can build that list by querying both the objects . They are related by the way one strategy can have multiple funds. The funds table contains the stragtegy foreign key

Comment: I just changed this line that is assigning to strategyFunds , from new ListItemVM() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).ToList();   to  new ListItemVM() { Id = y.Id, Name = y.Name }).ToList();  and can see the fundnames but however I can there are some missing srategies that have the investmentstatus invested in the list. Wondering if Union is doing the damage

Comment: I mean in one query. You still don't tell which data layer is involved. If this is Entity Framework you could do one query with `Include` and build the required output much easier.